# How to make generate QR Code Image with empty in center?

Tags: ios, qr-code

I want to generate a qr with empty in center.
Because i want to put a image in the center, such as a company logo.
But after i put a image in the center, the QR Image is not readable.

Is that any way to do it in IOS SDK?

Comment: Can you increase the redundancy of the code to make it bigger? Then a smaller logo in its centre should not compromise its integrity too much.

Comment: This Quora [discussion](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-generate-QR-codes-with-text-or-logos-embedded) has some suggestions.

Comment: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/qr-code-generation-swift/

Comment: This one is great as well: https://medium.com/@MedvedevTheDev/generating-basic-qr-codes-in-swift-63d7222aa011

Answer (score 3):

The QR Code on its own is fault tolerant. That means you can just overlay an image in the middle and still QR code will be scannable. [Refer Wiki Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Error_correction)

I do suggest to set input correction level to H.

Following is a Swift code to generate QR code from Data.

```
func generateQRCode(data: Data) -> CIImage? {
    // Setup filter to generate QR code using data
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")

    filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    filter?.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

    return filter?.outputImage
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
var str = "This string is used to generate QR code."
let userData = str.data(using: .utf8)
let qrCodeImage = generateQRCode(data: data)
```